# Using Visual SOURCESAFE

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am new with a program SourceSafe Explorer and I want to do one thing using it, I want to save a project state, and if I will change project in future, that I will be able to return this point,
can anyone help me and show how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the SourceSafe tutorial below to learn the basics on how to use the source control tool:
http://www.codepool.biz/sourcesafe-vss-how-to